# Get the app version from Play Store for updating the app in device. Ionic + Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, ionic4, capacitor

Whenever I upload a new version of my app in Play Store, I want to show user in app that newer version is available please update the app after detecting the version. I am building my application using Ionic and Capacitor.

Now I have gone through many blogs and stackoverflow questions in which developers has mentioned about the MS App Center or Cordova App Update but I don't want to do using these two. I just want to get the version from Play Store of the same application and if the version mismatch then I will show an alert to user for app update.

I have also seen the blogs related to `Jsoup.connect(...)` which is nothing but Native approach to get the version from Google Play Store but not reliable.

Is there any way to get the version from Play Store using any Capacitor plugin or something or even if Cordova App Update is the way to get the version in Ionic then how can I use the same in my Ionic + Capacitor based project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I propose an Workaround when ever your application initialized you can use `HTTP` request to your server and get the latest Version from your Own Database. and you can show Alert it will be more reliable. when ever you update app on play store just update your DB with new version number and show alert in the application.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib that's the last option I have if I don't get any solution at Play Store Level.

Comment: Hey, any news about your question ? Did you find a solution ? I'm in the same situation :'/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this promising repository of capacitor plugins. They are called **Capawesome Team**.

So far I haven't tested it. However I am going to. I will get back to you once I have news.

[GitHub - Capawesome Team - Capacitor App Update](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-app-update#usage)